# Calculating minutes from now until something is due

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have a project that needs me to accept an input for when (during the same day, I assume) an assignment is due.  I was trying to follow some code from a similar question but it's giving me an error, which I assume has to do with time_t and int values. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 int hour_input,min_input;

 cout << "What hour is your assignment due?\n";
 cin >> hour_input;
 cout << "What minute is your assignmnet due?\n";
 cin >> min_input;

 struct tm* tm;
 time_t ts = time(NULL);
 long int delta;
 tm->tm_hour = hour_input;
 tm->tm_min = min_input;

 delta = mktime(tm) - ts;
 delta += 24*60*60;
 cout << "There are "<< delta << " minutes until your assignment is due!\n";

 return 0;
}
```

What I'm looking for is some guidance on how to use the functions within the `<ctime>` header properly, thanks for your help!

Comment: added the homework tag, sure looks like it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double deltaMinutes = difftime(later,earlier) / 60.0;
```

I'd initialize each time struct to the current date. Note, that 1970 is designated by 70 in member tm::tm_year.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/difftime/

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, the part that seems to be getting me is getting the current date for the "earlier" argument of `difftime()`

EDIT: So I'm guessign I"m going to be using the `localtime()` function to accomplish this, so now I got to figure that out.

Comment: Totally got it figured out!

Used `tm_hour` and `tm_min` members of `struct tm` to get values of the local time and just subtracted, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The first error is you creating a pointer to `struct tm` but not pointing it to anything. You don't need a pointer:

```
struct tm tm;
/* set fields */
time_t timestamp = mktime(&tm);
```

The second error is that `mktime` expects a complete data/time in the structure. If the year, month and day all is zero then the returned time will be the first year, month and day. The call may actually fail because date must be between 1 and 31.

This means it's not easy to use `struct tm` for differences. Instead use `difftime` as suggested by Sam.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the salient bits from your code (and your declarations are in a very strange order)

```
 struct tm* tm;
 tm->tm_hour = hour_input;
 tm->tm_min = min_input;
 delta = mktime(tm) - ts;
```

So, tm is uninitialised and pointing to a random location. Moreover, you don't fill the structure in properly, and you have a random (probably invalid) year, month, day and seconds.

mktime will try to make this valid, but if seconds is sufficiently large it'll cause real havoc with your hours and minutes. Assuming the program doesn't crash before it gets that far. You didn't say what error you were getting.

Comment: Yea, I've been cutting and pasting like crazy, I apologize for the sloppiness.

Comment: Used a similar solution to what  you posted, didn't even need the delta variable in it, thanks for your help!